# Spring 5 Reactive - WebExceptionHandler is not getting called

Tags: spring-boot, exception, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have tried all 3 solutions suggested in [what is the right way to handle errors in spring-webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575538/what-is-the-right-way-to-handle-errors-in-spring-webflux/45280499#45280499), but `WebExceptionHandler` is not getting called. I am using `Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7`. Github repo [here](https://github.com/legendjaks/reflux)

```
@Configuration
class RoutesConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var testService: TestService

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var globalErrorHandler: GlobalErrorHandler

  @Bean
  fun routerFunction():

    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> = router {
    ("/test").nest {

      GET("/") {
        ServerResponse.ok().body(testService.test())
      }
    }
  }


} 


@Component
class GlobalErrorHandler() : WebExceptionHandler {

  companion object {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalErrorHandler::class.java)
  }

  override fun handle(exchange: ServerWebExchange?, ex: Throwable?): Mono<Void> {

    log.info("inside handle")

    /* Handle different exceptions here */
    when(ex!!) {
      is ClientException -> exchange!!.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
      is Exception -> exchange!!.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    }

    return Mono.empty()
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

When I change Spring Boot version to `2.0.0.M2`, the `WebExceptionHandler` is getting called. Do I need to do something for `2.0.0.M7`?

**SOLUTION:**

As per Brian's suggestion, it worked as

```
@Bean
@Order(-2)
fun globalErrorHandler() = GlobalErrorHandler()
```

Comment: anyone know how create a WebExchangeBindException easily?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can provide your own `WebExceptionHandler`, but you have to order it relatively to others, otherwise they might handle the error before yours get a chance to try.

- the `DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler` provided by Spring Boot for error handling ([see reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-webflux-error-handling)) is ordered at `-1`
- the `ResponseStatusExceptionHandler` provided by Spring Framework is ordered at `0`

So you can add `@Order(-2)` on your error handling component, to order it before the existing ones.

Comment: Spring boot built-in `AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler` seems more friendly for global error handling of web pages based applications. For REST applications, I think it is better if providing a `@RestControllerAdvice` like solution to set http status and entity.

Comment: I can't make RestControllerAdvice to catch errors before DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler or a custom WebExceptionHandler...

Comment: @Order(-123) definitely should solve a problem to ask spring context apply bean earlier

Answer (score 5):

An error response should have standard payload info. This can be done by extending `AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler`

**ErrorResponse**: Data Class

```
data class ErrorResponse(
    val timestamp: String,
    val path: String,
    val status: Int,
    val error: String,
    val message: String
)
```

**ServerResponseBuilder**: 2 different methods to build an error response

- **default**: handle standard errors
- **webClient**: handle `webClient` exceptions (`WebClientResponseException`), *not for this case*

  ```
  class ServerResponseBuilder(
          private val request: ServerRequest, 
          private val status: HttpStatus) {

      fun default(): Mono<ServerResponse> =
          ServerResponse
                  .status(status)
                  .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(ErrorResponse(
                          Date().format(),
                          request.path(),
                          status.value(),
                          status.name,
                          status.reasonPhrase)))

      fun webClient(e: WebClientResponseException): Mono<ServerResponse> =
          ServerResponse
                  .status(status)
                  .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(ErrorResponse(
                          Date().format(),
                          request.path(),
                          e.statusCode.value(),
                          e.message.toString(),
                          e.responseBodyAsString)))
  }
  ```

**GlobalErrorHandlerConfiguration**: Error handler

```
@Configuration
@Order(-2)
class GlobalErrorHandlerConfiguration @Autowired constructor(
        errorAttributes: ErrorAttributes,
        resourceProperties: ResourceProperties,
        applicationContext: ApplicationContext,
        viewResolversProvider: ObjectProvider<List<ViewResolver>>,
        serverCodecConfigurer: ServerCodecConfigurer) :
        AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler(
                errorAttributes,
                resourceProperties,
                applicationContext
        ) {

    init {
        setViewResolvers(viewResolversProvider.getIfAvailable { emptyList() })
        setMessageWriters(serverCodecConfigurer.writers)
        setMessageReaders(serverCodecConfigurer.readers)
    }

    override fun getRoutingFunction(errorAttributes: ErrorAttributes?): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> = 
        RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.all(), HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> { response(it, errorAttributes) })

    private fun response(request: ServerRequest, errorAttributes: ErrorAttributes?): Mono<ServerResponse> =
        ServerResponseBuilder(request, status(request, errorAttributes)).default()

    private fun status(request: ServerRequest, errorAttributes: ErrorAttributes?) =
        HttpStatus.valueOf(errorAttributesMap(request, errorAttributes)["status"] as Int)

    private fun errorAttributesMap(request: ServerRequest, errorAttributes: ErrorAttributes?) =
        errorAttributes!!.getErrorAttributes(request, false)
}
```